# How do I store an NSRange in a NSMutableArray or other container?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsobject, nsrange

Here's what I want to do:

```
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0,5);
id a = [NSMutableArray a];
[a addObject: r]; // but NSRange is not a NSObject *
```

With a boolean, I'd use code like this:

```
[a addObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];
```

or with an integer:

```
[a addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 3]];
```

So what's the equivalent with a `NSRange`? What I don't really want to do is create my own subclass of `NSObject` to accomplish this. Surely there's a way with what Apple's already provided?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

[Use NSValue's `+valueWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue/1410315-valuewithrange?language=objc). To retrieve the range structure back, use the [property `rangeValue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsvalue/1413902-rangevalue?language=objc).

```
[a addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:r]];
...

NSRange r = a[4].rangeValue;
```

Comment: Why NSValue could store NSRange but NSArray could not?

Comment: Because `NSArray` can store objects only. `NSRange` is not an object, but you can wrap it with `NSValue` so it can be used by `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` etc.

Comment: while iterating through NSMutable array , NSRange r = a[i].rangeValue  giving error like property range value not found on type id...

Comment: @jayantrawat: The type of the array `a` should be generic: `NSMutableArray<NSValue*>*`.

Answer (score 13):

```
[NSValue valueWithRange:r];
```

and get it back out with:

```
NSRange r = [rangeObject rangeValue];
```

Comment: what is rangeobject?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to store the `NSRange` in a property list, you can also turn an `NSRange` into an `NSString` using the `NSStringFromRange` function. And then, you can turn that string back into a range using the `NSRangeFromString` function.

Comment: Upvoting because this is clever and useful, but NSValue seems less elbowy. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks! I just learned about `NSValue` myself from the other answers (thanks @mipadi and @KennyTM), and it's definitely less elbowy than my suggestion. To be more deserving of your kind upvote, I updated my answer to mention that the string version can be useful with storing ranges in property lists.

Answer (score 4):

One other option might be to add those ranges into an `NSIndexSet`, depending on how you intend to use them next.